# Need suggestions for proof involving factors of factorials.

Tags: proof-verification, factorial, factoring

I have been using this expression for many years without encountering a counter-example, but I can't take it beyond $k=10000$, so I thought a proof would ease my concerns.

For $k\geq 1\land 2\leq n\leq k+2,$
    $$\frac{\binom{k n}{k}^2}{k! (k n)!}\equiv\frac{(k n)!}{(k!)^3 ((k n-k)!)^2}=\frac{p_i\cdot p_{i+1}\cdots}{\text{very large number}},$$
    where numerator $p_i\cdot p_{i+1}\cdots$ is the product of primes in $(kn-k,kn].$

The LHS simplifies to the center expression, to which we will refer for the remainder of this discussion.

Using this expression to prove that the numerator will always contain at least one prime is beyond known techniques.
But there is one aspect that needs a proof --- is the denominator large enough to cancel all primes $< kn-k$ which are in the numerator?

What would be a good approach to proving this? A pointer to appropriate literature will help, too.

**Edit** fixed prime indexes.

**Edit** after reading @GrumpyParsnip's suggestion, I was able to simplify my expression to: $ \frac{(k n)!}{k! (k n-k)! \left\lfloor \frac{k n}{2}\right\rfloor !}$, which I can prove using the Sylvester-Schur proof by Erdos.

Comment: It's unclear to me what your question is. Are you asking whether reducing your fraction to lowest terms always leaves primes in the numerator in the range specified? Why did you start indexing your primes at $n$?

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip, First question: that cannot be proved. Second question: $n$ is arbitrary. It is the number of the least prime in that range.

Comment: Is the "very large number" in the denominator supposed to be relatively prime to $p_n,p_{n+1},\ldots$?

Comment: So your question is whether the reduced form of the fraction only has primes $>kn-k$ in the numerator? (Which includes the case that there are no primes in the numerator.)

Comment: @AlexR., yes. The denominator does not go as high as the numerator.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip, YES.

Comment: My suggestion for proving this is to use Legendre's formula for the power of primes $p$ in a factorial. http://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/LegendresTheorem.shtml

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip, looks good, thanks.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip, could you make the suggestion an answer, so I can sign off on it?

Comment: @FredKline: done. Did you manage to prove it using Legendre's formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion for proving this is to use [Legendre's formula](http://cut-the-knot.org/blue/LegendresTheorem.shtml) for the power of primes $p$ in a factorial.

Comment: Erdos proved that the binomial has primes $> k$, so if we divide by half of $nk$, we cancel those primes, leaving only $1$ or the product of the primes $> nk-k$.. He did not address the primes $> nk-k$ because of the exceptions.

Comment: My conjecture at this point is that by using multiples of $k$ we avoid the exceptions. But we also have to have the limit $2\leq n \leq k+2$ to make it work.